# Bluetooth headphones work for audio, but built-in headphone mic doesn't

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I'm using Pop_OS! 20.04. I have a pair of Sony Bluetooth headphones ([wh-1000xm3](https://www.sony.com/electronics/headband-headphones/wh-1000xm3)). I'm using a [USB dongle](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00E38N7QE/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) for a Bluetooth receiver.

The audio works in the headphones, the on-headphone controls work, but the built-in mic doesn't. The mic and audio work with my Android phone, Windows, and Mac.

I went into settings and everything looks right, but the OS isn't detecting it. In Slack and Google Hangouts, there's a message saying that it can't be found as well as this online test https://www.onlinemictest.com/.

Are there any tools I can use to debug this? How can I figure out if it's the Bluetooth receiver, or something in my OS or the headphones?

I've tried blueman, but I didn't see anything out-of-the-ordinary.

I've tried this https://askubuntu.com/a/1233446/566235 but I don't know which one to add to my alsa-base.conf. My codec is Realtek ALC888

Screenshot of my audio settings, I can't unmute the input for my headphones.
[image: screenshot of my audio setting.]

The input for pavucontrol. The last one are my headphones.
[image: screenshot of pavucontrol input]

All the requested output:

```
$ bluetoothctl devices
Device 70:26:05:8C:CE:40 LE_WH-1000XM3
Device DC:2C:26:D0:90:6A RK-Bluetooth keyboard
Device CA:1C:83:E2:08:59 BT4.0+2.4G Mouse
Device E0:9F:2A:08:10:43 Intuos BT S
Device E0:EA:E1:C3:44:22 Inspire 2

$ bluetooth show
Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:11 (public)
    Name: pop-os
    Alias: pop-os
    Class: 0x001c0104
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: yes
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
    Pairable: no
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
    UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0535
    Discovering: no
Advertising Features:
    ActiveInstances: 0x00
    SupportedInstances: 0x05
    SupportedIncludes: tx-power
    SupportedIncludes: appearance
    SupportedIncludes: local-name

$ bluetoothctl info 70:26:05:8C:CE:40                                             
Device 70:26:05:8C:CE:40 (public)
    Name: LE_WH-1000XM3
    Alias: LE_WH-1000XM3
    Class: 0x00240404
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00000000-deca-fade-deca-deafdecacaff)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (7b265b0e-2232-4d45-bef4-bb8ae62f813d)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (81c2e72a-0591-443e-a1ff-05f988593351)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (931c7e8a-540f-4686-b798-e8df0a2ad9f7)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (96cc203e-5068-46ad-b32d-e316f5e069ba)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (b9b213ce-eeab-49e4-8fd9-aa478ed1b26b)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (f8d1fbe4-7966-4334-8024-ff96c9330e15)
    Modalias: usb:v054Cp0CD3d0452
    ManufacturerData Key: 0x012d
    ManufacturerData Value:
  04 00 01 31 00 01 ba 5c 10 b9 00 60 d0 00 00 00  ...1...\...`....
  00 00 00                                         ...             
    ServiceData Key: 0000fe26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    ServiceData Value:
  0a c9 5c                                         ..\             
    ServiceData Key: 0000fe2c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    ServiceData Value:
  0a c9 5c                                         ..\             

$ lsusb -v | grep -E '\<(Bus|iProduct|bDeviceClass|bDeviceProtocol)' 2>/dev/null
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  iProduct                2 
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 1224:2a25  
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  iProduct                2 
      (Bus Powered)
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
  bDeviceClass          224 Wireless
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Bluetooth
  iProduct                2 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  iProduct                1 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  iProduct                2 
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 045e:0291 Microsoft Corp. Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
  iProduct                0 
      (Bus Powered)
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 25a7:fa11 Nordic 2.4G Wireless Receiver
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  iProduct                2 
      (Bus Powered)
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  iProduct                2 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04b3:3025 IBM Corp. NetVista Full Width Keyboard
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  iProduct                2 
      (Bus Powered)
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  iProduct                2 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  iProduct                2 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  iProduct                2 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  iProduct                2 
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  iProduct                2 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  iProduct                2
```

Comment: What happens if you install and run "pavucontrol"? Check the "Input Devices" tab to see if it's muted. (That's where I would start.)

Comment: In pavucontrol is says my headphones are a monitor. I wonder if that has something to do with it.
https://imgur.com/a/JDR9jZ9 Screenshot of pavucontrol in action.

Comment: I'm just spitballing here, but can you click the arrow and select something other than 'monitor'? I take it that it wasn't muted?

Comment: I'm unable to unmute my microphone.

Comment: Sony's page state this: "Smart Listening by Adaptive Sound Control automatically adjusts ambient sound to your activity"

This may cause your unmute issues.

Comment: Brand/model of your computer?

Comment: Is your dongle B00E38N7QE Bluetooth 4.0? I couldn't find its specs. There seems to be a review on Amazon, which says that "It doesn't appear to support HSP bluetooth profile." HSP - Headset Profile for bluetooth. That would explain why you cannot switch from A2DP profile to enable mic. Then, your OS settings are not the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
You have the dongle ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio.
These are known to be of low quality, e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208296/bluetooth-adapter-configuration-issue-id-0a120001).
If possible, you may try following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1250273/226614).

---

It would help a lot if you post some info:

1. Output of

   ```
   $ bluetoothctl devices
   $ bluetoothctl show
   $ bluetoothctl info <address of headphones>
   $ lsusb -v | grep -E '\<(Bus|iProduct|bDeviceClass|bDeviceProtocol)' 2>/dev/null
   ```
2. Captures of what you see when you click on the down arrows in Output device and Input device of the image you show (so we see all available options).
3. Captures of what you see when you click on the down arrows in `pavucontrol` -> *Output Devices* and *Input Devices*.

In the meantime, you can try (all from SE, no need to copy-paste, at least until having some more info):

1. [This sequence](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232155/226614).
2. `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`.
3. [This sequence](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233446/226614).
4. [This sequence](https://superuser.com/a/1423564/245595).

**Possibly Related**:

1. https://gist.github.com/nevack/6b36b82d715dc025163d9e9124840a07
2. https://github.com/mechaHarry/realtek-alc888-patched
3. https://askubuntu.com/questions/287235/realtek-alc888-sound-card-doesnt-work-after-ubuntu-13-04
4. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/no-sound-or-bad-sound-card-with-codec-realtek-alc888-861049/
5. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04
6. [Force headset mic as default microphone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646669/force-headset-mic-as-default-microphone)
7. https://superuser.com/questions/1588750/mono-mic-instead-of-stereo-sound-for-bluetooth-headphones-on-ubuntu
8. https://askubuntu.com/questions/816879/why-do-my-bluetooth-sony-stero-headphones-only-play-in-mono
9. [Debian systems seems to recognize speakers but not the headphones for Lenovo laptops](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157131/debian-systems-seems-to-recognize-speakers-but-not-the-headphones-for-lenovo-lap)
10. https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/mate-20-04-headphone-mic-combo-jack-not-detecting-headset/21731

Comment: Great info! For the 3rd sequence you posted, I found my sound card codec - Realtek ALC888, however, I don't know which one to add to alsa-base.conf from kernel.org. How do I find that out?

Comment: @alanj -
1) Please post all of the requested info. Moreover, for the output that is text in a terminal, it is best if you post it as markdown formatted code, instead of a screen capture. that helps others help you.
2) Did you follow step 2 in sequence 3? What did you find?

Comment: Turns out it *doesn't* work on the same machine with Windows 10. I wonder if it's worth pursuing any more or is it un-fixable. I'll post all that output in my question later today.

Comment: @alanj - I find it strange that those expensive Sony headphones do not work 100% in Windows 10... I am sure you can make it work in Win 10, and I would be confident you can also get it working in Linux. See https://ap.community.sony.com/s/question/0D54O00006Ogzz9SAB/no-microphone-on-windows-10-with-sony-wh1000xm3?language=en_US

Comment: 1st and 2nd sequence: no change. 3rd: see above. 4th: not applicable since my headphones aren't plugged into my computer.

Comment: Wait, it also doesn't work in Windows 10 ? Have you installed the official drivers there ? This clearly points to a Bluetooth issue or a protocol one (APTX, etc bluetooth has lots being the huge mess it is). Also, the more a device is expensive and new, the more likely it will use proprietary or unconventional hardawre/sofware. Hence sometimes paradoxal worse support.

The wh-1000xm3's page states these protocols: DSEE HX™ (seems proprietary) and LDAC.

Comment: Yes. I'm on Windows 10 right now and the headset doesn't work (not even the output which used to work). Would a new/better bluetooth receiver help in this case?

Comment: @alanj - What do you mean by "used to work"? What changed between then and now?

Answer (score 1):

PulseAudio supports only 2 profiles:

- A2DP with good quality, but no audio input
- HSP/HFP with both audio input and output and much worse quality

It seems, that you have enabled the A2DP profile. You can change it in pavucontrol tab "Configuration", where you should see your BT headphones with "Profile" dropdown.

[image: A pavucontrol window with visible profile dropdown with tree options: "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)", "Headsed Head Unit (HSP/HFP)" and "Off]

Related StackExchange questions:

1. [Use high-quality codec and microphone simultaneously with Bluetooth headset](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616973/use-high-quality-codec-and-microphone-simultaneously-with-bluetooth-headset)
2. [How to keep the audio profile at A2DP while using a mic with Bluetooth headset? (Push-to-talk)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004712/how-to-keep-the-audio-profile-at-a2dp-while-using-a-mic-with-bluetooth-headset/1250010#1250010)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bluetooth issue, your best bet is to fiddle more with `blueman` as some people also had to do that to make their bluetooth headset works in the past.

Sometimes, you'll need to pair your bluetooth device directly with `blueman` rather than with Desktop Environments' GUI.

This is where you should fiddle with (Connect, Pair, Trust, Setup...):[image]

I also see this: [image]

Shouldn't "Monitor of WH-1000XM3" be set as the fallback ?

You may also mute any other input devices and see if they don't make any conflicts.

Try to set Slack and Hangouts to the right device on pavucontrol too: [image]

Comment: What do you mean by set as the fallback?

Comment: You set a fallback device by ticking the "green check" symbol to the corresponding device. In your picture, your fallback is currently set as "USB PHY 2.0 Mono". About Slack and Hangouts, have you tried to change the device on pavucontrol first too ? i.stack.imgur.com/CpkfC.png

Comment: In Bluetooth Devices, I right click my headphones and go to "Audio Profile", when I select "Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)" I get a message "Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit"

Comment: So that's a bluetooth issue. Sometimes it uses another audio profile there, you'll have to try them all

Did you make sure that your PC has the right Bluetooth version ? E.g Bluetooth 3.0 on PC vs Bluetooth 4.0 on your headphones and you'll miss some protocols like Bluetooth Low Energy in that example.

Comment: When I go here: https://www.onlinemictest.com/ and I enable the browser to use the microphone and I speak, nothing happens. But while I'm listening to music, the line moves as if the mic is picking up the music.