# guide to bluetooth headset and audio profiles

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth

I'm using Archlinux on a Lenovo Thinkpad, which generally works great.
I have a lot of online meetings, and so I have a variety of bluetooth headsets to choose from. I use `bluez` and `blueman` with the `blueman-applet` to manage my connections, and then `pulseaudio` to do the actual audio routing from my applications (zoom, skype, you name it) to the devices.

Two headsets in question that I use are

- Bose QC35 II
- Google Pixel Buds A-Series

For either of these, whenever I connect to them, the audio profile selected by pulseaudio is "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP)", which is (as far as I understand) a Sink-only profile, so that's not too useful for me, because I also want to use the microphone.

For the Bose headset, it shows me that "Headset Head Unit (HSP)" is unavailable. I don't know why that is, but I suppose this is just a property of the headset that they don't support that profile.

Hence, I have to change to "Handsfree Head Unit (HFP)" in order to actually make the microphone work, which is fine.

Now, here's the issue: Whenver I make that switch, I all of the sudden hear a very low-level, but clearly recognizable static noise, which is pretty annoying.
I'm sure this is a software-side problem, because it instantly goes away if I switch back to the A2DP profile.
On the other hand, it also seems to be connected to the specific hardware, because I don't encounter that behavior with my Pixel Buds.

I assume there is some bug in the default configuration of `bluez`/`blueman` that causes this behavior, because the headset works perfectly when connecting to my phone.

So, in summary, my question is: Where can I find information about the configuration options for my headset, and does anyone have an idea what specifically might be causing the static noise and how I could get rid of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use high-quality codec and microphone simultaneously with Bluetooth headset](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616973/use-high-quality-codec-and-microphone-simultaneously-with-bluetooth-headset)