# What are and how to use the different bluetooth profiles?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, video

I am trying to troubleshoot this problem: [After pause no sound with UE Boom bluetooth speaker on Macbook](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/711201/341192).

When the speaker is connected, and I pause a playing stream for some time (more than just a few seconds though), no matter the player, there is no sound in the speaker when un-pausing the player.

Reconnecting the speaker fixes this, but that is annoying and not permanent.

Another way is to change the bluetooth profile:

[image]

Only "high fidelity" options are usable, the others trigger distorted sound. When the problem happens, changing between the high fidelity profiles has no effect. But changing to one of the other options makes the speaker work, only with distorted sound. But switching back at that point to one of the high fidelity profiles fixes the problem.

I was thinking that learning more about these options my lead to some clue as to how to get a permanent fix for the initial problem, which seems to be affecting all the "high fidelity" profiles.

Comment: The HFP ones are for when you want to use the microphone (e.g., video calls), the A2DP ones are for when you don't need the microphone (so _everything_ else).

Comment: If the A2DP profiles don't work, make sure that the output devices for the applications are set to them (for some reason, they're often set to the HDMI outputs in my case unless I disable the HDMI outputs completely beforehand)

Comment: @muru - A bit confusing! is HFP suposed to mean "high fidelity playback"? those are the same as the A2DP in my list, right, as seen in parenthesis? Or is HSP referring to the other 3, "headset head unit" (HSP/HFP in parenthesis)?

Comment: @muru - anyway, I cannot use the last 3 in the list,   the"headset head unit" (HSP/HFP) (sound distorted), but the first 3 are affected by the pause/mute problem.

Comment: HSP or HFP, either one, should only be used for when you need the microphone. These profiles have got a codec upgrade in recent times and sound better than they did before, but they're still only for when you're calling. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/616973/70524

Comment: HSP is *Head Set Profile*, HFP is *Hands Free Profile*. HSP includes only volume control, while HFP includes a way to control a mobile phone remotely (dial/answer/hold/end call etc.) and provisions for echo cancelling, which is a requirement in speakerphone-style hands-frees.

Comment: @telcoM - In the list I have for this device HSP/HFP are not separated, and they are also useless: the UE Boom speaker lacks a mic, and the sound is awful with these profiles (last 3 in the image). The first 3 ("high fidelity" A2DP-sink), have fine sound, but affected by the linked bug.

Comment: Yes, HSP and HFP both use codecs optimized strictly for speech only, so the results for music are not expected to be great. Apparently HFP version 1.6 introduced the ability to select different codecs and the mSFP wideband speech codec.