# Force headset mic as default microphone

Tags: pulseaudio

Is there any way that I can force pulseaudio on Debian to use the headset mic option as the microphone instead of internal? You can manually set the mic to "headset mic" even when its unplugged in `pavucontrol`. For some reason the headset mic isnt getting automatically switched, and since the internal mic is never going to be used I don't need pulseaudio to switch to anything, just stay on the headset mic.

I did find a fix that allowed the mic to automatically switch over, but it had a nasty sounding pop any time you plugged in any audio device which was not what I wanted.

Since you can manually set the mic input to a headset mic (even when not plugged in), surely there is way to change the default so that the internal mic is never used?

Comment: Can you post a picture so we can see where's your issue better ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the internal microphone config file at `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-internal-mic.conf` and add the following lines:

```
[Jack Headphone Mic]
required-any = any
state.plugged = no
```

This will disable the internal microphone from being accessible when a headset microphone is plugged in. Most likely will need to make this modification again after a pulseaudio update.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer for a plugged-in headset.
Would you be able to provide the right lines for a bluetooth headset?

Answer (score 1):

you can either try to disable the internal mic or set another one as default.

To disable the internal mic, run

```
pactl unload-module "MODULE ID"
```

You can find your Module ID listed as 'Owner Module' by running:

```
pactl list sources
```

The output should look something like this:

```
Source #2
State: SUSPENDED
Name: alsa_output.usb-Corsair_Corsair_VOID_PRO_Wireless_Gaming_Headset-00.iec958-stereo.monitor
Description: Monitor of Corsair VOID PRO Wireless Gaming Headset Digital Stereo (IEC958)
Driver: module-alsa-card.c
Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Owner Module: 24
Mute: no
Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
        balance 0,00
Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.usb-Corsair_Corsair_VOID_PRO_Wireless_Gaming_Headset-00.iec958-stereo
Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
Properties:
    device.description = "Monitor of Corsair VOID PRO Wireless Gaming Headset Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
    device.class = "monitor"
    alsa.card = "1"
```

To set another microphone as default

```
pactl set-default-source 'SOURCE ID'
```

The Source ID being the Source #, the top line of the previous command output.

Comment: Doesn't work for analog headsets, they show up as "ports" under a source that I need in pactl

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood from your post, all you have to do is:

- `mute` and `silence` your `internal` port
- Switch your port to `headset mic (unplugged/plugged)`
- Unmute it and set a volume to it
- Tick the `set as fallback` button (the roundy "green check" symbol).

Comment: This works until I unplug the headset, then the audio input source switches to "Internal Microphone" and undoes any fallback settings I have set in the `pavucontrol` application.

Comment: Damn, this means you'll have to fiddle with pulseaudio files so it keeps the configuration, which is unfortunatly a huge can of worms.